# How to connect GoogleApiClient with AppInvite.API enabled?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-invites

When I read the doc of app invite (https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android) they say that to Receive invitations

> The code above requires a connected GoogleApiClient with AppInvite.API
>   enabled.

but i have no idea how to do this ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Firebase Invites Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/invites/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/invites/MainActivity.java) project.

There is also general information in the [Guide for Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).